# SQL Server - simple remote reporting tool?

Tags: sql-server

I want to give a client access to a SQL server instance so they can execute a stored proc, or run a view, but ideally I don't want to give them SQL Server management studio as they are non technical.

Are there any free and easy to use remote admin / reporting utilities for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008, [Report Builder 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f783224-9871-4eea-b1d5-f3140a253db6&displaylang=en) (free download) is a tool designed to allow end users to create reports from a variety of data sources including views and report models.

More information [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/report-builder.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of.

It sounds to me like you would be better off creating a simple web form/win form that provides your client with access to only the specific features and processes they require. Doing so would avoid confusing the client with all the unecessary complexity that manage studio would present them with.

I'm no programming guru but putting something basic together like this, say using .NET, could be done in a couple of hours, inluding impementing apporpriate security. I suspect you could probably find all the information you require in order to do this on the ASP.Net tutorials.

http://www.asp.net/learn/

Comment: yeah thats the work i was hopinh to avoid - i know it isnt a big deal though so maybe thats what i will end up doing..

Comment: You're welcome. I think it would be your best option. Once you have something in place, it would not require much effort to add additional features as and when a client requests them. You could also re-use the basic framework for other projects in the future.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access isn't free, but if they already have it then you're set.  Just create an Access Data Project (adp) against the database, and only give them execute access on the views/stored procs that you want them to use.  It's simple point-and-click for them to run a sproc, and it prompts them for the parameter values.

Comment: Access is perhaps too powerful; it's easy for marketeers to end up with databases that take ages to reverse engineer. Reporting Services (or report builder) is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

If its a specific stored procedure or its to view a specific view, why not write your own single purpose application? It shouldn't take long at all and then you will control the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old but I am still posting for others. I built a small web application that does just that. Basically you input the server, catalog, user, password and the sql query and you get a URL that points to that query/report. You give the URL to the intended users and they'll be presented by the data generated from the query in tabular format. It also includes features such as pagination, filtering and sorting.
You can download it from http://klauscam.github.io/EasyReportingTool.